# How to make Python read multiple txt files

Tags: python

I need help with this Python Script 
 I am a noob to Python, but I really need this to work 
I have over 200.txt files all located in different folders and subs, and in each txt file I have 2 codes that need to be edited

This is what I have going now and this works great but I have to rename the script to match the file name

```
f1 = open('(1).txt', 'r')
f2 = open('(1A).txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('"aplid": 2147483648', '"aplid": -2147483648'))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

This is my goal for the script to read `anyfilename.txt` in any folder

```
import glob
import os

for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
f1 = open('f', 'r')
f2 = open('f', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('"aplid": 2147483648,', '"aplid": -2147483648,'))
    f2.write(line.replace('"orlid": 2147483648,', '"orlid": -2147483648,'))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

I made a batch script for this project and it works great, but it's super slow, it would be faster for me to edit the python script for each txt file lol..

I don't know if Python can read Folders and subfolders like batch `dir /b /s /a-d`

I'm sorry for bothering you'll, but I searched online and I can't find anything that helps with this and most of it I don't understand

I keep reading that using a path can help, but this script is going to be placed in several computers so using path is not best

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to *focus* your question and ask more clearly. Make sure you have *one* question to ask per post. Keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum or a tutorial resource. I can't understand what you mean with most of this. Are you actually able to write code that edits every file? Is it just *slow*, or does it *not work*? If it doesn't work, *what happens*, and *how is that wrong*? Do you actually *understand* how paths work with `open`? Do you know what *relative* and *absolute* paths are? Do you know what a *current working directory* is?

Comment: You can still use path even if the script is to be used in several computers. If you use os.getcwd() you get the current working directory, so if the file is placed in the same/similar directory as the txt files then you just need to add the extra levels to the path. If several people are using your script then consistency in directory between all of you is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to traverse through a directory tree:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        if os.path.splitext(name)[1] != '.txt':
            continue
        nmin = os.path.join(root,name)
        with open(nmin,"r") as fin:
            data = fin.read()
        data = data.replace('"aplid": 2147483648,', '"aplid": -2147483648,') \
                   .replace('"orlid": 2147483648,', '"orlid": -2147483648,')
        with open(nmin,"w") as fout:
            fout.write(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been looking for days, I really would love to learn python, but I learn better when someone teaches me how things work, I'm more into batch but a lot of my projects require python. I have this one project that would be awesome to have python work on, but I can't figure it out, this script might help me with that, that project I had to make 200 scripts and each script edits 8 named.txt files, so 1 script needs to find code "50" and replace it with "City" and this code is located in 8 different txt files,  so 8 files per script times 200, and this takes 6 hours

Comment: question: is there a way to make this script read like this `('"aplid": *,', '"aplid": -2147483648,') ` to wear it finds `'aplid"` , and replaces with `"aplid": -125632156,` like making the `find="aplid": ,"` is this possible for python

Comment: So replace `"aplid": <anynumber>,` with `"aplid": -2147483648,`"  Sure, you can do that with a regular expression search.  The `re` module even has a `replace` option.  You'd have to research regexes a bit.

Comment: Thanks again, hey question this` ('.')` appears to be editing the `.py script` as well, I'm calling the `.py` from a batch choice menu and it edits every file plus the script, I tried this `('.txt')` and `('*.txt') and nothing, if I double click the .py it's fine

Comment: OK, I think I got it, see this is how I learn this things, doing this `('.')` edits every file and the script when I `CALL`, doing this `('Folder\.')` only targets that folder and skips the `.py` script, I understand  this `('.')` this reads any file with a period, the good thing is that the only files I work with are .txt files and .jpeg, so once again thanks, and I will research the regexes

Comment: The parameter to `os.walk` is the directory to start in.  If you need to filter the files, you can do that as the first thing in the `for` loop: `if os.path.splitext(name)[1] != '.txt': continue`

Comment: OK, great Thank you

Comment: I wish I could buy you a beer, with your help I was able to upgrade and replace another batch script, this other project that I had mentioned to you in a earlier comment would normally takes 5 to 7 hours I now can do it in 2 seconds, man your the best, also I'm having an issue running a call command with python, any ideas I did share another ask with the issue, I open one batch to call another batch and the second one calls the py, but it fails

Comment: on your last comment you said if I need to filter the .txt, turns out I need to control the file it reads I need this to only read a certain txt file will this ` for loop: if os.path.splitext(name)[1] != '.txt': continue` be able to control this, and will this go on top of this `for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):` or will this get replaced